# OSX Lion and Java DB

Tags: java, osx-lion, javadb

Two part question...

> 1. I've read in other posts that Apple's personal version of Java is
>      deprecated.  If I am running lion and already their personal
>      version installed, what problems will occur if I install the version 7
>      from Oracle.  Will it run out of the box or will there be conflicts?
>      What configuration is necessary. Will I loose  the apple look and feel
>      by default on apps.
> 2. Is Java DB installed by default with the Apple version of the JDK. Is it installed with the Oracle version for OSX Lion?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Strange, went I checked the supported OS's for jdk by Oracle, only Linux, Windows, and Solaris are supported, which doesn't make sense if the Apple version is deprecated.

Comment: There is no official `Oracle java` that runs on Mac - only that is available is a [preview](http://jdk7.java.net/macportpreview/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The official Oracle Java 7 will be out [later this year](http://campustechnology.com/articles/2011/10/06/oracle-previews-java-se-7-for-mac-os-x-unveils-java-se-roadmap.aspx) It's not currently supported on the mac.
2. It's not, but since it's just a repacking of Apache Derby, you can go grab [that](http://db.apache.org)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, Apple will no longer release their own version Java/JDK implementation for OSX. OpenJDK project will take over its role. Please take a look at project websites below.

http://openjdk.java.net/

http://code.google.com/p/openjdk-osx-build/